# How much electrical power is needed to melt a wire?

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity, thermoelectricity

I saw a video in which someone melted a metal wire with electricity.

How much electrical power would this take?

Comment: There's no direct correlation between Amperes and heat.  It's not really clear what you're asking here.

Comment: i saw a video on internet with someone who melted metal with electricity and I am curious how much power do you need to melt it instantly.

Comment: Power is different than amperage; and "instantly" actually has some time required.  This would be a heat transfer problem; and depends on quite a few factors.

Comment: @Scriptarus would you please reword your question to reflect what you asked in the comment?

Comment: I have certainly crossed some wires at times and seen the metal connectors melt "instantly", from the standpoint of human perception.  But your question is really meaningless without some parameters on the current source, type and mass of metal, and the meaning of "instantly".

Comment: Consider an old-fashioned incandescent flashlight bulb.  A couple of D cells make it light brightly, but the filament doesn't melt since tungsten has such a high melting point.  But if you replaced it with a similar sized thread of steel it would melt as soon as you turned on the flashlight, probably in less than a tenth off a second.

Comment: You are asking about the design of a fuse and 45 seconds into this video you will see a demonstration of a nail which melts when the current is a few hundred amps. So look up "design of fuses".

Answer (score 7):

The electric power running in a wire is given by $P = V^2/R$, where $V$ is the voltage and $R$ is the resistance. The resistance is given by $R = \rho_e l/A$ where $\rho_e$ is the resistivity of the metal, $l$ is the length of the wire, and $A$ is the cross sectional area. So the power is given by $P=A  V^2/\rho_e l$. This is the amount of heat per unit time produced as a result of connecting this wire to a $V$-volt battery.

Now, if the wire is supposed to melt quickly, we can assume that all of this heat is used for heating and melting of the wire, and there is not enough time for it to dissipate the heat to the environment. The heat required to do so is the heat required to raise the temperature to $3695 K$ (**Edit**: this number was originally given in the question) plus the heat required for melting:

$$Q = m C \Delta T + m L_f,$$

where $m$ is the total mass, $C$ is the specific heat (heat required per unit mass of raising the temperature with one degree), $\Delta T$ is the change in the temperature, and $L_f$ is the latent heat of melting (heat per unit mass required to melt). The mass of a wire is the given by its mass density times its volume, which is length times cross section: $m=\rho_m l A.$

For the wire to melt we need $Pt>Q$, where $t$ is the total time. Note that we need to keep $t$ small so that the heat does not dissipate to the environment.

Let us put everything together:
$$Pt>Q\implies \frac{A  V^2 t}{\rho_e l}>\rho_m l A(C \Delta T + L_f)\implies V>\sqrt{\frac{\rho_m\rho_e l^2(C \Delta T + L_f)}t}.$$

From the melting point being $3695 K$, I can guess that your metal is tungsten. For tungsten we have 
$$\rho_m=19250 kg/m^3,\quad \rho_e=52.8 n\Omega m,\quad C=134J/kg K,\quad and\quad  L_f=192000J/kg. $$

Let us assume the room temperature is $295 K$. Then $\Delta T=3400K.$ Plugging in everything, we have:
$$V>\frac{l}{\sqrt{t}}\sqrt{19250 kg/m^3\times52.8 n\Omega m \times(134J/kg K\times3400K+192000J/kg) }=\frac{25.6vol.s^{-1/2}.m^{-1} l}{\sqrt{t}}.$$

Assuming I haven't made an algebraic mistake, and assuming all of the generated heat goes into the wire and not the environment, in order for the wire to melt in $1$ second, you will need $\sim 26$ volts per meter length of the wire to melt it.

Realistically, a lot of the heat will be lost to the environment. In particular, the hot wire starts radiating light which one needs to take into account.

**Update 1**: Let us add the effect of radiation. The power of radiation is given by $\sigma T^4 S$, where $\sigma =  5.6703\times 10^{-8} W/m^2K^4$, and $S = 2\pi r l$ is the surface area of the wire. I'm going to make the assumption that all of the radiation takes place at the melting temperature to simplify the problem. In order to include this, we need the input electric power minus the output radiation power together satisfy $Pt>Q$. That is
$$
(\frac{A  V^2}{\rho_e l}-\sigma T^4 S)\,t >\rho_m l A(C \Delta T + L_f)\implies V>l\sqrt{\frac{2\rho_e\sigma T^4}{r}+\frac{\rho_m\rho_e(C \Delta T + L_f)}t},
$$
where $r$ is the radius of the wire (assuming cylindrical wire).

To melt a wire with $1$ mm radius, in one second, we need about $42$ volts per meter of the wire. This still seems low to me. Can anyone catch a mistake in my calculation?

**Update 2**: As JMac mentioned in the comment below, the resistivity of tungsten is highly temperature dependent. The value provided above is at $20^\circ$C. The value of $\rho_e$ near the melting temperature is about $20$ times larger. So the answer is somewhere between $3$ to $4.5$ ($\sqrt{20}\sim4.5$) times larger than calculated above.

Comment: There sin't a mistake - but to maintain 42V along a meter of 1mm radius wire you would need a LOT of amps.

Comment: Where did you find that resistivity of tungsten, and what temperature was it for? (it increases by a factor of 20 by the time you reach the melting point vs. room temperature)

Comment: @JMac From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tungsten .  It is given for $20^\circ C$. Is it strongly temperature dependent?

Comment: @stochastic http://physics.usask.ca/~bzulkosk/Lab_Manuals/EP354/ep354_thermal-radiation-lab_Tungsten-Temp-Resistivity.pdf Highly.  That's why you're getting such low voltage requirements, your $R$ is too low.  I'm not sure how easy it is to add an estimate of that effect though.

Answer (score 2):

This answers your comment, not the question itself (which doesn't provide enough information to answer).

To melt something you first need to provide heat to it till it reaches the melting point. The formula for that is $H = mc\Delta T$, where $m$ is the mass, $c$ is a constant that depends on the material you're melting, and $\Delta T$ is the change in temperature. For example to bring ice from -50 celsius to 0 celsius (when it melts), $\Delta T$ is 50.

After bringing the metal to the melting point, you need to actually melt it. The formula for that is given by $H = mL_f$, where $m$ is the mass, and $L_f$ is a constant known as the latent heat of fusion. This constant measures the amount of energy required to melt the material, and depends on the material in question.

Once you have the amount of heat required, you need to match that to the heat generated by electricity. This is given by the formula $H = I^2R$, where $I$ is the current and $R$ is the electrical resistance of the metal. The electrical resistance itself is dependent on factors such as the temperature of the metal, the type of metal, and so on. Note the resistance depends on the temperature of the metal, which is changing as you heat it. This means that you'll need to use calculus. If you're only after the order of magnitude, you can treat the electrical resistance of the metal as a constant, and elementary algebra will give you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am giving you a very rough answer here and will try to read other more elaborate answers later to learn!

I have done welding on small household jobs such as repairing the metal railing and what not! I used to have a 75 amp welding machine and it easily melts 1/8 inch thick electrodes!

So roughly 110volts. 75amps= 8250watts.

And it melts it so fast that you need to learn how to control the job otherwise you will make a hole in the base material!

Comment: The welding arc isn't at 110V. You can't take 75amps from a 110V outlet. So the voltage at the electrodes is generally only around 15-20 volts to allow it to operate from a 10-15A outlet

Comment: Yes, it's right. Although by experience we have learned that you need to plug your welder to a main outlet if you don't want to hazard tripping the breaker or overheating the electrical cables.

Comment: @martin beckett The voltage isn't low simply because of receptacle limitations, though. It's low because the heat for the welding is generated by having an enormous current flux for the amount of contact area. Constant-current supplies are used; they vary voltage to compensate for slight variations in distance, while the constant current provides consistent heating. The voltage needs to be exactly as high as is required to drive the specified current flow.